# Import all and import certain elements in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am currently learning Python 3.xx (3,8 currently to be more specific) as first language and am seeing all the time something like

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
```

Now my question here is...:

when you import from tkiner *(therefore all) why do you import again certain elements? Should it not be included in all ( * )?

Thank you in advance for your time and effort spent on answering my question and have a wonderfull day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line will import `tkinter.font`, which is a submodule.

`import *` won't import submodules.

```py
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> font
>>> from tkinter import font
>>> font
<module 'tkinter.font' from 'lib/python3.7/tkinter/font.py'>
```

Another case where `*` would not import everything is when the module has an `__all__` attribute. (Search for "public names" in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) here.)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot for the really quick and on point answer :)

Comment: @AKX Can you explain what do you mean by `submodule`? I understand a `subpackage` - another folder(having `__init__.py`) inside the main folder).

Comment: See above – `tkinter` itself is `tkinter/__init__.py` on disk; `tkinter.font` is `tkinter/font.py` on disk.